# call custom event function for HTML elements in VBScript

Tags: html, dom, vbscript

I just want to call function for custom elements in VBscript. following are my current script code. but its crashing my application. (target browser is internet explorer)

```
  Function SampleFunction()
  msgbox"samplemessage"
  End Function
  set ResponseFn = getRef("SampleFunction")
  set element = document.getElementById("elem id")
  element.addEventListener "OnResponse, ResponseFn , false
  set cEvent = document.createEvent("CustomEvent")
  cEvent.initCustomEvent "OnResponse", false, false, null
  element.dispatchEvent(cEvent)
  element.removeEventListener "OnResponse\", ResponseFn , false
```

any idea why above code crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that above code will support only in IE 9. other versions of IE wont support this. Need to add following tag in htm file for supporting above code

"meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" "

This solved my issue